# statistical aggregation over mysql table

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, olap

In my application I have a table `products_downloads` where I'm storing information about each product download.

This is a structure of this table:

[image]

In my application I have a lot of product TOPs where I'm showing last 10 products sorted by total downloads(all time) and another one sorted by last week download count(sql query execution time minus 7 days)

For example at my homepage I need to show TOP product downloads for all products on my website. At some product category I need to show product downloads TOP with a products only related to this category and all descendant categories.

I feel that I need to perform some periodic data aggregation(over `products_downloads` table) but I don't understand what is a correct solution for this task right now.. Maybe OLAP ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing uses the following basic pattern

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) hit_count,
        product_id
  FROM products_downloads 
  WHERE whatever-condition
  GROUP BY product_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

The aggregation you want is straightforward: `COUNT(*)`.  The trick is to pick suitable `WHERE` conditions.